# Comparable vs similar when talking about data

Tags: word-usage

So I'm writing an IELTS essay and wonder if **comparable** is used properly in these sentences.

1. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts (18% and 6% respectively). As for people replying with other reasons, the figures for emigrants and immigrants were more **comparable**, at 14% and 11% in that order.
2. Only about 1% of the people over 34 frequented the cinema once every month in 1984, with a subsequent rise to 15% 16 years later. A **comparable** change, but to a much greater extent, can be seen in the figure for those under 15, which grew sharply from around 17% to 58% by the end of the period.

The second paragraph is from another essay of mine where I also question the use of **comparable** myself. In both cases, I know **similar** is likely to fit the context, but I want to have an alternative. Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: Be aware, questions that ask for writing help without identifying a clear problem and focus are off-topic here. This does focus on one word, but you don't explain why you have misgivings about it.

Comment: So in the Cambridge Dictionary, its meaning is "similar in size, amount, or quality to something else", so it seems to me that I can use it and "similar" interchangeably when comparing sizes, amounts or qualities. However, I'm still unsure about whether or not people actually use the word like I do, because I didn't find a similar example on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Although "Comparable" is colloquially used to mean "similar", in the you mean here, it correctly means can be compared. Hence "more comparable" makes no sense, and comparable on its own wouldn't be helpful. Apples, oranges and lemons are equally comparable but oranges and lemons are more similar than oranges and apples.